# Trouble with the Buffer using bluetooth of android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, buffer

I'm using the bluetooth of an android phone to send some data (strings) to an arduino with bluetooth device.

All works like charm... but I can only send 325 strings!!! (each string only contains 2 positive int numbers).

After this, at the logcat of eclipse, appears me this message: "rfc_setup_rx_bufout of buffer: rfc_setup_rx_bufout of buffer: Out of Buffers" each time that the android tries to send a new data.

I can't close the bluetoothsocket and reopen it (or connect) during the application cause I need to send data very fast for my purpose(about 100-200 ms one after another) and there's no time for that. How can I "clear" the buffer? Is it really the problem with the buffer??

Part of the code I'm ussing this:

```
    <code>

private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null; 
try { 
            btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);

       } catch (IOException e) { 

       } 
           try { 
                outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream(); 

           } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.e(TAG, "ON RESUME: Output stream creation failed.", e); 
           } 

byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes(); 
           try { 
                outStream.write(msgBuffer); 

           } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.e(TAG, "ON RESUME: Exception during write.", e); 
           } 


</code>
```

The "message" in message.getBytes(); is actually the string that I'm sending.

Another thing:  I'm ussing an array (byte[] msgBuffer). Is there anyway I can make a "loop" to get to the [0] or [1] index after sending the data so this string will never be full cause I would only use 2 values.

Or the problem is with an internal buffer of my phone (samsung GT-I5500) and no with the code?

A will really apreciate any help cause I'm stuck in this.